# Rate Limiting An API

Tags: authentication, api

I am busy developing an API for a mobile application, currently one of the endpoints require that the users username and password be POST'ed to it. What I am worried about is someone discovering that API endpoint and brute forcing username/password combinations.

Should I be rate limiting my API? If so, do I need to worry about this now or only down the line if this type of attack actually takes place?

Answer (score 1):

Rate Limiting your API endpoint is a good start. However it can be easly bypassed by using proxies or tor sockets for example. What I'd suggest you is to implement a mechanism that validates the request. HMAC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC is a common cryptography authentication protocol that uses shared secret aswell as hashing algorithm. It obviously has some downfalls. Shared secret can be found in a process of reverse engineering your mobile application, thus you should also do proper code obfuscation. It provides extra layers of security and increases attack difficulity and cost.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to make a limit of accesses by the users to avoid brute force.
To this you can implement something that checks attempts by a specific user login or specific IP, like Fail2ban do, and then you block access to this user account or IP.
To identify if a user is trying to brute force your API you can analyse the time between the attempts, if they are too fast and on a large scale. Another approach is to check if the same user account is trying to login from different IPs in a short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you may implement a challenge instead of basically pushing the password over API.
For example, the well-known (and still in use in IMAP) [CRAM-MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRAM-MD5) may be used.

Using this kind of mechanism, a brute force attack may only lead to a *one-time access* to the API but not to the leak of user password.