# API open endpoint best practices

Tags: authentication, api

I am currently developing an [API](https://expressjs.com/) for my front-end [React](https://reactjs.org/) application. All my routes (besides the two I'll mention below) are secure by the use of JWTs. They get generated once a user logs in and is then used for the remainder of the session. The app to API connection will be over HTTPS so it should hinder MiTM attacks.

The two endpoints (which you have probably guessed) is the login and register endpoint. I have come across [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/200674/rate-limiting-an-api) that suggests using HMAC. If I understand it correctly, the front end will create a hash (using a shared secret) of the request body and send it with the request; once the request arrives the API will generate a hash (with the same shared secret) based off of the request and compare the two hash values. If they don't match then the request was tampered with or is fraudulent.

So that obviously verifies the integrity of the requests made. The other problem is now that, anyone can just spam the hell out of the endpoint and effectively DoS/DDoS the endpoint. Even though the requests are fraudulent, the request will still be tried to be verified on the API side by calculating the hash. Which takes compute power. So if I am getting a lot of requests, very quickly, it will drag my API down.

Would it be right to say that I need to rate-limit the endpoint based on the request IP address? Say limit the call to 10 per hour from a specific IP address? Would appreciate any feedback with regards how to stop the *spamming* of the endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

As with many security models, a multi layered approach might be more suitable for the login use case.

Here are some suggestions:

1. As you already mentioned, rate limiting policies for the API would prevent attacks coming from the same client (DOS).
2. Implement a Proof-of-Work system in the API - see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash. This would make it expensive for the client to calculate a hash but cheap for your server to validate.
3. Use CAPTCHA like Google's Recaptcha https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify. Admittedly this helps mitigate brute-force attacks, not DDoS.
4. Front your API using a cloud provider then use DDoS protection service from your cloud provider to detect suspicious traffic and slows them down at the Edge before they hit your server.